# Objective C how to refer to a view in a class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My app has multiple views to add buttons programmatically and instead of having the following instance method in each controller, I would like to put the method in a common class as use it as a class method.

```
+ (void) addLeftImageButton:(UIButton *)leftButton:(float)x:(float)y:(NSString *)name:(int) tag
{
     leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [leftButton setTag: tag];
     [leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 345.0, 345.0);
     [self.view addSubview:leftButton];
}
```

The question I have is how to refer `self.view` to the calling view. as `self.view` is not known in the common class.

Comment: Does the view depend only on the controller, or each controller might have more than one view to manage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, a class method has no concept of `self`. You need to pass the view as a parameter.

```
+ (void)addLeftImageButton:(UIButton *)leftButton:(float)x:(float)y:(NSString *)name:(int) tag forView:(UIView *)view;
```

Comment: that works. One further question, how in the class method would I refer to the selector method that's in the calling class [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you saying you want to call that method from your class method?

Comment: If you want to set the button target/action, pass the object and the selector (data type `SEL`) into the class method too.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is to leave the step of adding the subview to the controller itself, making this the class method:

```
+ (UIButton *) leftButtonWithImageName:(NSString *)imageName x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y tag:(int)tag
{
     UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [leftButton setTag: tag];
     [leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 345.0, 345.0);
     return leftButton;
}
```

In a view controller:

```
UIButton *leftButton = [MyClass leftButtonWithImageName:@"image.png" x:0 y:0 tag:10];

[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:leftButton];
```

A few reasons behind this:

- If you're using this for multiple view controllers, your class method doesn't have to assume that they all implement the same `buttonPressed:` method, which isn't a safe assumption.
- To someone just looking at your view controller code, it will look like nothing calls the `buttonPressed:`.
- Callers of the `leftButton...` method will have more control over the button. For example, they might want to add the button as a property in `viewDidLoad` so its properties (like its frame) can be queried, but not actually add it to the screen until after an animation completes.

You might also consider making all the view controllers a subclass of a superclass, but that's a very implementation specific decision.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common method for all your controllers you should add it as an instance method in a base controller that all your other controllers inherit from.

Also, there are a few of weird things about that method:

1. Why do you pass `leftButton` as a parameter when the first thing you do is overwriting its value?
2. Your method declaration is really weird. Did you read the warnings? I think you want it to look more like this:

   ```
   - (void)leftButtonWithImageName:(NSString *)name
                                 x:(CGFloat)x
                                 y:(CGFloat)y
                               tag:(int)tag
   {
        UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [leftButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [leftButton setTag:tag];
        [leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:name]
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 345.0, 345.0);
        [self.view addSubview:leftButton];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this . But a common class is not good one.

The best way is that you put this function as a category of UIViewController. This is instant method (-)but not class method(+)
You don't need to change others.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIViewControl (labels)
-(void) add left...
@end
@implementation UIViewControl (labels)
-(void) add left...{}
@end
```

Put above code in a file "labelcontrol.h" and "label control.m"

Then in your any viewcontroller.m
Add: import "labelcontrol.h" to make it work

Comment: I don't think a category is the best way, but if he is going to use a category he should at least follow the naming convention: `UIViewController+XYZLabels.h` and `UIViewController+XYZLabels.m`for the implementation, which should not be in the header file. I think a common base class is better design.